# Cakephp Cookie gets deleted automatically when session timesout

Tags: php, session, cookies, cakephp-2.0

I am writing a cookie for auto login users.
It works almost flaw less. But when the Session times out the cookie gets deleted, although it's set for 30 days.
I can't understand why this is happening.
If I close the browser and reopen it, all are fine, but if I leave the browser open and let the Session time out the cookie gets deleted to.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'KPD',
    'timeout' => 180,
    'cookieTimeout' => 30 * 1440
));
```

**UPDATE:** I found the problem but I don't have a solution! The problem is that when I rewrite the Cookie nothing happens, even if I try to delete it, and rewrite it.
I have a cookie as an array User.remember = array('token' => TOKEN). When I try to rewrite the token, the cookie remains the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are not defining the value (in number of minutes) of `Session.cookieTimeout`, you should define proper value for [Session.cookieTimeout](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html). If it is not defined it will use the same value as `Session.timeout`

Comment: Indeed I had only Session.timeout set, I have now set Configure::write('Session.cookieTimeout', 30*1440);
Configure::write('Session.timeout', 180); I presume this should work, no?

Comment: the cookie still gets deleted after a while. When I close the browser and open it after a hour, lets say, It still askes for login, and the cookie is deleted. So it is acting the same. Any ideas?

Comment: I have noticed that after writing parameters individually I then wrote again Cookie::write("Session", array('defaults' => 'php')); thus overwriting the initial parameters, I am waiting now to see if it worked. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like it remains written as long as the Session.timeout, here 180minutes.